# Determinants of $I+A$ and $I-A$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A$ be a $4\times4$ matrix with $\det(A) = 2$, find $\det(I+A)$ and $\det(I-A)$/

I read that we need the trace to find $\det(I+A)$, but I do not know how to find it when we only know the determinant of $A$. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible to work it out with that information. Try substituting different diagonal matrices in as $A$.

Comment: Not enough information to find $det(I+A)$ and $det(I-A)$

Comment: @geetha290krm What if we also know the value of Sp$A$, as the questioner proposed?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your matrix takes values in $\mathbb{R}$, then there is no unique answer without additional information.

To see this, let
$$
A:=
\begin{bmatrix}
c & 0 & 0 & a \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a=\frac{4c-1}{2}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
We have $\det A=2$, but $\det (I+A)= 9c+\frac{63}{2}$ and $\det(I-A)=-c-\frac{1}{2}$.
Since $c$ is arbitrary, $\det(I+A)$ and $\det(I-A)$ can be arbitrary.

---

Even if we fix the trace of $A$ to be a constant $s$,
the answer is still not unique.
Let
$$
A:=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & h \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & s-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $h\in\mathbb{R}$.
It is easy to verify that $\det(A)=2$, but $\det(I+A)=4+2s-4h$,
which is arbitrary.

Sidenote: In the 2D case, $\det(I+A)$ and $\det(I-A)$ are actually uniquely determined by $\det(A)$ and $\text{tr}(A)$.

Comment: The questioner rightly proposed that Sp$A$ may also be needed to calculate the two determinants. In this particular example, the knowledge of Sp$A$ fixes the value of $c$,, and the answer becomes unambiguous.

Comment: @Michael_1812 Answer still not unique (assuming what you mean by $\text{Sp} A$ is $\text{tr} A$). Updated.